# Client side not getting download file from server

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I got an express server that sends back a file as a response,
but the thing is, I'm trying do the get request from the client with a different origin, I've enabled cors on my server, but my client isn't getting back the response file.
I'm using `express's` in build module, `res.download(file)` to send the file.

I've tested it by sending a `post` request from a different origin to my server, and the client got response back, but when I send a get request to download a file, my server received the request, but it seems the client isn't get the response file.

Is there some additional headers I need to set to make this work?

Code server side:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.get("/download/:downloadId",async (req,res) => {



    let downloadId = req.params.downloadId;
    console.log(downloadId)
    let fileName = glob(MYPATH,{},(err,files) =>{
        // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.download(files[0],"filename",{headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*"}})
    })



})
```

Code client side:

```
const getFileName = (header) => {

    const fileName = header.headers.get('content-disposition').split('filename=')[1].slice(1,-1)

    return fileName
}

const downloadFile = async () => {
   let file =  await fetch(`${urlDownload}/` + downloadUserId )

let blobObj = {
       filename:getFileName(file),
        blob:await file.blob()
    }

    console.log(blobObj)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting on the client side?

Comment: You should definitely share the relevant part of your code for better help.

Comment: Could you please provide the endpoint code example?

Comment: @mousetail no errors, it's just that the client isn't receiving the files from response

Comment: So what is wrong with the response exactly? Is it empty? Is it a 400 error? Does it time out?

Comment: @mousetail it got a 200, the file was downloaded, my code for fetching the file and renaming it still returned the file is null, I had to go to the network tab, and manually click on the download link.

Comment: What do you mean not downloading? The response is empty?

Comment: @mousetail so apprently since the response type is cors, I tried to console.log the resposne.headers.get('content-disposition'), but it was null, even though I could find the headers in the browser's network tab.

Comment: I would recommend including the solution below in the "Answers" section to make it easier to find for future visitors to this question, instead of in the body of your "Question", and to better fit the Q&A format of Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103768/accessing-response-headers-on-cors-request) , apparently it was because cors only enable certain headers that a client can access from a response.

The header I needed was not enabled by default,and my client side javascript code needed that header's value to complete the download.

So I needed to add this header(`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`) in my server's response's header with the value of the allowed headers apart from the default ones.

Something like this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers','Content-Disposition')
```